# How to encrypt/decrypt foreign language

Tags: encryption

My algorithm takes plain English text and converts it to ASCII code. Then it is followed by encryption and decryption algorithm.

How to encrypt/decrypt any other foreign languages eg. Chinese sentence?

Comment: Uhm, use UTF-8 instead of ASCII?

Comment: If the algorithm works on the base of (8 bit) bytes, then the Unicode of a Chinese glyph is 2 bytes and you can do a corresponding adaptation. Otherwise I doubt you could easily do something with it.

Comment: So, you are using a custom cipher? This is not generally recommended. It is recommended to use an existing reviewed cipher (e.g. AES-GCM), ideally within an existing and reviewed scheme (e.g. TLS, PGP, …). Not doing so is very error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

**Modern cryptography does not work on *characters*, but on *bytes*.** It is the user's responsibility to convert their message (which may consist of human-readable text, audio or video streams, etc.) to a string of bytes. This is done using an **encoding**: For instance, PNG is a method to convert image data to bytes; MP3 is a way to convert audio data to bytes; and likewise ASCII and UTF-8 are basically descriptions of how to convert *characters* to bytes and back.

In your case, simply using UTF-8 (or any other Unicode-capable encoding) in place of ASCII should do the trick.

Comment: PNG and MP3 are mainly data compression techniques that already take bytes as input. They may also leak data through side channels. So maybe they are not the best examples to be used here. Bitmaps or wave encoding may be better examples.

Comment: thank you. So characters are converted to byte and later it is encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at just the byte stream, it will not matter what language it is:

```
中国话  : 4e2d65fd8bdd
english: 656e676c697368
```

You should just take the stream of raw data and encrypt it.

Comment: thank you. So characters are converted to byte and later  it  is encrypted.

Comment: just read the byte stream.